# What is the set $f(D)$, i.e., the image of $D$ by $f$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry

Let $1<a<2,0<b<1,c>1$ be real numbers. Let us consider the triangle $$D=(0,0)(c,0)(0,c-1)$$

and consider the function $f:ℝ²→ℝ²$ defined by

$$f(x,y)=(1-ax+y,bx)$$

My **question** is: What is the set $f(D)$, i.e., the image of $D$ by $f$.

I have no idea to start.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @Test123: I have no idea to start.

Comment: Try calculate the image of the three vertices of $D$ for the limiting values of your parameters. Then check where does $f$ sends lines to find the image of each side of $D$.

Comment: Can you convince yourself that the images of straight lines under this function will be straight lines? Then clearly the intersection of the straight lines will be preserved, which would imply that simply joining the images of the vertices is sufficient.

Comment: @UdayKhanna: Can you write this as a typical answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, observe that by the linearity of the function it is evident that any straight line is being mapped to a straight line and thus it is sufficient to observe that the images of the vertices $(0,0),(c,0),(0,c-1)$, which are $(1,0),(1-ac,bc),(c,0)$ respectively determine the triangle that is f(D). Here there exist one common point $(c,0)$ between $D$ and the image of $D$.

Explicitly, If you break down the figure into lines and try to find the images of the lines then it is still a straightforward task. We have $D$ as the right angled triangle formed by the intersection of the lines which I will represent in their parametrised form

{$(t,0): 0<t<c$},   {$(t,(c-1)(1-\frac{t}{c})):0<t<c$} , {$(0,t):0<t<c-1 $}

Now the images of these lines are

{$(1-at,bt): 0<t<c$},  {$(c-(a+\frac{c-1}{c})t,bt):0<t<c$}, {$(1+t,0):0<t<c-1$}

And it can be easily observed that these three straight lines intersect at the three distinct points stated earlier forming the image triangle f(D).